# Overwritting bootstrap hidden-xs media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using the really useful bootstrap hidden-xs, visible-xs and so on classes to make a questionare page responsive.

One of my clients is embeding this page in his website and unfortunately, he can only support an iframe width of 700px.

So my problem is, that he gets the mobile version of the page in his website as the bootstrap xs starts at 767px.

So what can I do to change this behaviour to 650px?

My approach in my overwritting css is following but nothing changes:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }
    table.visible-xs {
        display: table !important;
    }
    tr.visible-xs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.visible-xs,
    td.visible-xs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .visible-xs-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .visible-xs-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .visible-xs-inline-block {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hidden xs is extra small (less than 768px).

Comment: Correct, but I want that to happen at 600px, not 767px.

Comment: Oh okay, then you can modify the main bootstrap.css file also, if you want it for whole application.

Comment: Sorry, you don't get what I'm trying to achieve. I DON'T want the switch at 768px and 767px but at 601px and 600px.

Comment: Yes, I could but I want to avoid changing the included (cdn) bootstrap css. Look at my solution below.

Comment: You will have to define for xs, sm, md and lg. since, if your mobile version comes on tablet, somewhere between 600-767px, you will still get mobile version. and also you will have to specify that sm ends at 600 and from 600 md and lg starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to create my own additional **xxs class** for that case. For everyone who runs into a similar issue here the css that needs to be added with your desired widths:

```
.visible-xxs,
.visible-xxs-block,
.visible-xxs-inline,
.visible-xxs-inline-block {
    display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .visible-xxs {
        display: block !important;
    }
    table.visible-xxs {
        display: table !important;
    }
    tr.visible-xxs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.visible-xxs,
    td.visible-xxs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .visible-xxs-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .visible-xs-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .visible-xxs-inline-block {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .visible-xs {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 601px) {
    .hidden-xxs {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 766px) {
    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }
    table.visible-xs {
        display: table !important;
    }
    tr.visible-xs {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
    th.visible-xs,
    td.visible-xs {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 766px) {
    .visible-xs-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 766px) {
    .visible-xs-inline {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 766px) {
    .visible-xs-inline-block {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
}
```